# facebook platform visual studio 2010 intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2010, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

does it exist a way to make intellisense work with `<fb:` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Visual Studio 2010 nor the Facebook C# SDK does not have intellisense for fb tags. You would have to write your own schema for visual studio.